# Read from spawned process hangs both processes

Tags: delphi, winapi, ipc

I'm trying to follow [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx).

I created a very simple console app.

```
Writeln('Take a nap.');
Sleep(1000);
Writeln('Done.');
```

I'm using the following code to launch the console app and (try to) read its output.  Both the console app and the main app hang.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  PATH: WideString = 'c:\tmp\nap.exe';
var
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
  WorkingDir: WideString;
  StdOutRead, StdOutWrite: THandle;
  Attr: SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;
  N: Cardinal;
  Buf: Array [0.. 5000] of Byte;
begin
  FillChar(Attr, SizeOf(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), 0);
  Attr.nLength := SizeOf(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
  Attr.bInheritHandle := True;
  Attr.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;

  if not (CreatePipe(StdOutRead, StdOutWrite, @Attr, 0)) then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  FillChar(StartInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), 0);
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  StartInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  StartInfo.hStdOutput := StdOutWrite;
  // I've tried creating pipes for stdin and stderr to no avail

  WorkingDir := ExtractFilePath(PATH);
  if not CreateProcess(nil, PWideChar(PATH), nil, nil, false, 0, nil, PWideChar(WorkingDir), StartInfo, ProcInfo) then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  // this call hangs -- the console app hangs regardless
  if not ReadFile(StdOutRead, Buf[0], Length(Buf), N, nil) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Any suggestions... unfortunately [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/07/10183884.aspx) didn't help either.

Comment: Your pipe creation code is incomplete. See MSDN for a more complete example: [How to spawn console processes with redirected standard handles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351)

Comment: @RemyLebeau In fact the only change needed to make the code in the question work is to inherited handles when calling `CreateProcess`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious flaw that I can see is that you set `bInheritHandles` to `False` when you call `CreateProcess`. You must pass `True` and when you do so your code works as expected. The output from `nap.exe` is faithfully read into `Buf`.

Comment: Thanks... I don't know how I missed that.